# Mid 2011 imac 27" with new hard drive keeps shutting down randomly

Tags: imac, shutdown

Mid 2011 imac 27" with new hard drive keeps shutting down randomly.

After a bad crash, the imac can no longer boot into desktop.
I seem to have a stuck booting cycle with the horizontal progress bar progressing
then reverting back to the spinning progress circle but never reaching desktop.

I can boot via an external hard drive with a system on and tried to backup
the problem drive with superduper. But halfway through backing up the imac
randomly shut down. I then restarted using the my external drive and backed up files
manuallly.

I also tried installing mavericks on to the problem drive, but the install
freezes at the end of the mavericks restart message.

Do you think I have a defective new hard drive?
Or do you think it's another issue with the imac?

I may try another option of formatting the problem drive and reinstalling
a completely clean system on to the drive.

Comment: did you try the fsck in terminal to see if it can fix the drive.

Comment: Not tried fsck, I will give it a go.

Comment: Fsck did't work. Have formatted drive, but can't seem to reinstall any system.